# Jpa com implementação hibernate não gera tabelas no postgresql

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Boa noite a todos estou utilizando a Jpa com a implementação hibernate para dentre outras funcionalidades gerar tabelas, o problema é que de uma hora para outra as tabelas pararam de ser geradas, alguém já passou por isso

segue meu persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="comunicaVisual"
    transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <!-- meu provider é o hibernate -->
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <!-- mapeamento das entidades criadas -->
    <class>br.com.drem.entity.Pessoa</class>
    <class>br.com.drem.entity.Cidade</class>
    <class>br.com.drem.entity.Estado</class>
    <class>br.com.drem.entity.Pais</class>
    <class>br.com.drem.entity.PessoaFisica</class>
    <class>br.com.drem.entity.PessoaJuridica</class>
    <class>br.com.drem.entity.Usuario</class>
    <class>br.com.drem.entity.Funcionario</class>
    <class>br.com.drem.entity.Venda</class>
    <class>br.com.drem.entity.Produto</class>
    <class>br.com.drem.entity.Contato</class>

    <!-- se determinada entidade não estiver participando da query ela vai ser excluida do trabalho -->
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes> 

    <properties>
        <!-- postgres é o nome da minha database -->
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/postgres" />

        <!-- drive do postgresql 9 -->
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />

        <!-- ususário da base de dados -->
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="postgres" />

        <!-- Senha -->
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="1" />

        <!-- nome do schema-->
        <property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="dremcom_drem" />

        <!-- metodo para criacao, atualizacao ou exclusao de tables -->
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />

        <!-- para visualizarmos as querys no console -->
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />

        <!-- para formatamos as querys -->
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />

        <!-- dialeto do banco de dados -->
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />


        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>

        <!--  -->
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class"
            value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory" />

    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: A propriedade que configura isso é a `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` e no seu caso está correta. Minhas perguntas são: Nenhum erro ou exceção é gerado? As permissões no banco estão corretas? Você consegue criar tabelas "na mão"?

Comment: consegui resolver o problema, o que fiz foi o seguinte fui no banco e delatei as tabelas na propriedade hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto coloquei como create executei o projeto novamente e depois mudei a propriedade hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto para update e funcionou, me parece que quando se deixa em update e faz alteração em uma tabela o hibernate não consegue manipular as tabelas como elas realmente deveriam ficar.

Comment: Achou alguma solução? Poste como resposta para ajudar outras pessoas.

Comment: ta ai @bigown segue como fiz para conseguir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passo 01: exclua totalmente o seu esquema em sua base de dados.
Passo 02: faça as alterações necessárias em sua conexão.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="comunicaVisual"
    transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <!-- meu provider é o hibernate -->
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <!-- mapeamento das entidades criadas -->
    <class>br.com.drem.entity.Pessoa</class>
    <class>br.com.drem.entity.Cidade</class>
    <class>br.com.drem.entity.Estado</class>
    <class>br.com.drem.entity.Pais</class>
    <class>br.com.drem.entity.PessoaFisica</class>
    <class>br.com.drem.entity.PessoaJuridica</class>
    <class>br.com.drem.entity.Usuario</class>
    <class>br.com.drem.entity.Funcionario</class>
    <class>br.com.drem.entity.Venda</class>
    <class>br.com.drem.entity.Produto</class>
    <class>br.com.drem.entity.Contato</class>

    <!-- se determinada entidade não estiver participando da query ela vai ser excluida do trabalho -->
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes> 

    <properties>
        <!-- postgres é o nome da minha database -->
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/postgres" />

        <!-- drive do postgresql 9 -->
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />

        <!-- ususário da base de dados -->
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="postgres" />

        <!-- Senha -->
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="1" />

        <!-- nome do schema-->
        <property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="drem" />


        <!-- para visualizarmos as querys no console -->
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />

        <!-- para formatamos as querys -->
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />

        <!-- dialeto do banco de dados -->
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />

        <!-- metodo para criacao, atualizacao ou exclusao de tables -->
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />


        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>

        <!--  -->
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class"
            value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory" />

    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

passo 3: crie novamente o esquema e em seguida rode o projeto.

obs: senhas de maquina local 0o

Comment: Você pode aceitar a resposta. Depois eu vejo se consigo entender e votar.